# Buttons for Filter Views

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, macro-recorder

I'm trying to prepare a large contact sheet on the new Google Sheets.

I want to be able to quickly filter through the data (7-8  presets). 
I was initially setting this up on Excel  using Slicers, which did the job quite well.

The Filter Views work pretty well for what I want, but I want it to show in the form of buttons showing up on the spreadsheet. Is there a Macro I can write to do this? Is there an API open that can access switching on and off of filter views?

If yes, that will do the job perfectly. If not, Can I call filters and not filter views somehow? And hardcode the filter conditions into the macro buttons?

In Short : I want toggle buttons to turn on/off all Filter Views.

Please drop in your suggestions about other alternatives to do this

Comment: Unfortunately, filter views cannot be managed programmatically: see [this feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524).

Comment: Did you realized any research effort before posting the question like reviewing the [Spreadsheets Service documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)? Reference: [ask]. By the other hand "drop your suggestions about other alternatives" makes this question to ask  for "opinion based" answers.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, I thought I'd share my solution:

Create a filter view, and look at the browser address bar. You'll see the URL for the filter view eg:

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq6yK7m3HxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxQyv3ASdA/edit#gid=10999999999999948&fvid=2049999999922

Note the numbers after #gid and &fvid which refer to the google sheet and filter view ID respectively.

Go to a cell within the spreadsheet and enter the formula:

> =hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq6yK7m3HxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxQyv3ASdA/edit#gid=10999999999999948&fvid=2049999999922", "Name of the filter view")

The cell will show the familiar blue underlined "Name of the filter view" and clicking on it will show the filter view.

Comment: This is a genius workaround, thanks for sharing! I don't need it any more but I might come back to this in the future.